# Mounting goes wrong

Tags: ubuntu, quota

I am using ubuntu 9.10 and following the next tutorial: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-9.10-ispconfig-3-p4. I am at point 15. This says i must install quota etc. This have i done.

Now i must add *usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0* to my /etc/fstab file. When i did this i had te next code:

```
/dev/xvda2      /             ext3     defaults,errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0 0
/dev/xvda1      none          swap     defaults                   0 0
proc            /proc         proc     defaults                   0 0
devpts          /dev/pts      devpts   gid=5,mode=620             0 0
```

I have run the commands *touch /aquota.user /aquota.group* and *chmod 600 /aquota.*

Now i must run the command *mount -o remount /* but when i do it i get the following error:

```
mount: / not mounted already, or bad option
```

When i delete the *usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0* it works fine. But this line must stand there. What is going wrong???

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try removing the word "defaults" from that options list.  You don't want the default options, you want all the stuff you provided.  Remove that, and see if it will remount properly.

So that first line should look like this:

```
/dev/xvda2      /             ext3     errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0 0
```